# Hexagon border around item title

Tags: html, css

I am building a hexagon shaped link and i got to the basic shape i want, but what i want to achieve next is to have a white hexagonal 2px border around my  whenever i hover. Basically another hexagon inside this one but with transparent content - only white border in shape of a hexagon.

```css
#hexGrid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 16px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.hex {
  position: relative;
  visibility:hidden;
  outline:1px solid transparent; /* fix for jagged edges in FF on hover transition */
}
.hex::after{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  padding-bottom: 86.602%;  /* =  100 / tan(60) * 1.5 */
}

.hexIn{
  position: absolute;
  width:96%;
  padding-bottom: 110.851%; /* =  width / sin(60) */
  margin:0 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  outline:1px solid transparent; /* fix for jagged edges in FF on hover transition */
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,-60deg) skewY(30deg);
}

.hexIn * {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  outline:1px solid transparent; /* fix for jagged edges in FF on hover transition */
}

.hexLink {
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate3d(0,0,1,60deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate3d(0,0,1,60deg);
  transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate3d(0,0,1,60deg);
}

.hex img {
  left: -100%;
  right: -100%;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg);
  transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg);
}
```

```html
<ul id="hexGrid">
  <li class="hex">
    <div class="hexIn">
      <a class="hexLink" href="#">
        <img src="https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4144/5053682635_b348b24698.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="hex-content">
            <h2>This is a title</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I tried going about this with another smaller hexagon inside this one but i couldn't achieve what i wanted.

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/4zscs68a/

Comment: Could you please create fiddle for the same. With the codes you provided,I'm unable to create a hexagon.

Comment: Added jsfiddle link

Comment: If it proves too tricky, have you considered using transparent / .svg images as div background?

Comment: Use SVG...soooo much simpler.